# Rails text_field_tag id attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input

I'm going through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial. One of the exercises for `chapter 8` is to rewrite the code using `form_tag` instead of `form_for`. After viewing the source that `form_for` was giving me and looking up each `tag` in the Rails documentation, I was able to successfully put it together.

My question is: How does Rails know what `id` attribute to give the  `<input>` tag created by `text_field_tag`, so that it matches the `id` of the `<label>` tag created by the `label_tag` that precedes it?

Here's the code for the form:

```
<%= form_tag(sessions_path) do %>

  <%= label_tag "session_email", "Email" %>
  <%= text_field_tag "session[email]" %>

  <%= label_tag "session_password", "Password" %>
  <%= password_field_tag "session[password]" %>

  <%= button_tag("Sign in", name: "commit", type: "submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the resulting html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="c9a5KJveRSOQyDo/ckUtpmQAbjw2f1alnB6Dn1lu3XU=" /></div>

  <label for="session_email">Email</label>
  <input id="session_email" name="session[email]" type="text" value="{:id=&gt;&quot;session_email&quot;}" />

  <label for="session_password">Password</label>
  <input id="session_password" name="session[password]" type="password" value="{:id=&gt;&quot;session_password&quot;}" />

  <button name="commit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

Comment: It does not know that, the id generated by the text_field_tag is either equal to the id option OR by the name of the input field where the '[' and ']' are replaced by underscores '_', which, luckily, matches your label's id

Comment: So Rails looks at `text_field_tag`, sees the first parameter is `"session[email]"`, and infers that the id it should assign to the resulting `<input>` tag is "session_email"?

Comment: Yep, it does not check for a label or whatever, it just follows a naming convention (Im sure you heard about it in Rails tutorials) which matches quite well each elements

Comment: Oh okay I know that the paradigm is "convention over configuration" but I'm not very used to it so sometimes I forget about it. But I'm getting used to it and it's really convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since Rails 5.1, the recommended form helper to use is [form_with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with).
And `form_with` no longer automatically generates `id`'s and `class`'s for DOM elements any more like `form_for` and `form_tag` used to.

This has implications for adding markup like `label`s which *used to* link up to their corresponding input fields automatically. *Now*, for a label to properly pair up to an input field (with the `for` attribute) you need to *explicitly* add the `id` attribute to the input.

#### Example

ERB:

```
<%= form_with model: User.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, id: :user_name %>
<% end %>
```

which generates HTML:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
  <label for="user_name">Name</label>
  <input id="user_name" type="text" name="user[name]">
</form>
```

#### See also

https://medium.com/@tinchorb/form-with-building-html-forms-in-rails-5-1-f30bd60ef52d, specifically the heading "No more auto-generated ids and classes".